# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bcadd()

Tags: php, nginx, bcmath

After installed "eduTrac SIS" and accessing "dashboard" got this error

Ubuntu 16.4, PHP 7.0(php7.0-fpm), Apache2, Nginx,

URL gives error 500 and nginx/error.log displays,

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Error: Call to undefined function PHPBenchmark\bcadd() in
>   /var/www/html/eduTrac-SIS/app/src/vendor/phpbenchmark/phpbenchmark/lib/PHPBenchmark/Utils.php:18

Answer (score 41, accepted):

PHP does not recognize "bcadd()" gives the error.
"bcadd()" function is included in "bcmath" PHP extention.

Just installing the relevant bcmath extension would solved the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmath
```

Please note, you should find the correct version of bcmath extension according to your PHP version.
And restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 6):

For PHP 7.4- bcmath, install with apt or yum as below:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-bcmath
```

or

```
sudo yum install php7.4-bcmath
```

Comment: It is important to restart the apache2 service so it recognizes it. Like in the @Isanka Wijerathne answer

Comment: Package 'php7.4-bcmath' has no installation candidate